# Problem on commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G'$ be the *commutator subgroup* of $G$. Prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $G'\subset H$, then $H$ is normal in $G$.

I do not know how to prove it. I have tried different ways but all of them were unsuccessful. However, I know that $G'$ is normal in $G$ and quotient group $G/G'$ is abelian.

Can anyone demonstrate how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: for $g \in G$ and $h \in H$: $g^{-1}hg=h \cdot h^{-1}g^{-1}hg=h \cdot [h,g]$. Or use the correspondence theorem and the fact that every subgroup of an abelian group is normal.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have done the same thing on my paper. Sorry, right now I have realized that $[h,g]\in G'\subset H$ and $h\in H$ so $h\cdot [h,g]\in H$ since $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: We know that $G/G'$ is abelian group and every subgroup of abelian group is normal hence $G'H/G'$ is normal. But $G'H/G'$ is the same as $H/G'$. How to use here the correspondence theorem? I am learning group theory from Herstein's book and there is no theorem which is called corresponding theorem but I guess that it is one of the isomorphism theorem. I know their proof but I don't know how to apply them in different cases. It would be great from your side if you will show it's application here. I would grateful for that.

Comment: OK, it is the fact that the subgroups of $G/G'$ correspond with those in $G$ containing $G'$. Exactly $HG'/G'=H/G'$ here.

Comment: But how are using here isomorphism theorem? Could you clarify it please?

Comment: Look at the canonical homo (not iso) morphism from $G$ to $G/G’$.

Answer (score 1):

If $h\in H$ and $g\in G$, you need to prove that $ghg^{-1}\in H$. You know that $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=h'$, for some $h'\in H$ (because $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}\in G'\subset H$). Therefore, $ghg^{-1}=h'h\in H$.

Answer (score 1):

*A simple variant:*

By definition, for any $h\in H$ and $g\in G,\,$ $\:ghg^{-1}h^{-1}\in G'\subset H,\,$ so $\;ghg^{-1}\in Hh=H$.

*With isomorphism theorem:*

The derived subgroups is the smallest normal subgroup such that $G/G'$  be abelian , and $H/G'$ is a (necessarily normal) subgroup of $G/G'$. Hence its inverse image in $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and as $G'\subset H$, this inverse image is precisely $H$.

Comment: Yes, it is nice. I have understood it immediately after first post :( But i would like to see it's proof via one of the isomorphism theorems. It would be very useful since i dont know how to apply them.

Comment: @RFZ: Your pleasure is my command, mylord!

Comment: Sorry i was not meant that. Please sorry, dear Bernard.

Comment: @RFZ:  Don't worry: 'twas just a joke :o)

Comment: Dear Bernard! Could you help me please with this topic?    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590072/application-of-automorphisms-in-constructing-groups/2590118?noredirect=1#comment5347980_2590118