# Application of automorphisms in constructing groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is an excerpt from Herstein's book. There are some moments which are unclear to me and I would like to clarify them.

[image]

They take two elements of set $\langle G,x\rangle$ (*this set is not yet a group!*) which consists of $21$ elements, namely, $xa$ and $xa^2$ and multiply them: $(xa)(xa^2)=x(ax)a^2$.

**Q1:** How did the author manage to write the product as $x(ax)a^2$? Why associativity is correct in this *set* $\langle G,x\rangle$?

**Q2:** We have that $x^{-1}ax=a^2$ in set $\langle G,x\rangle$. How did they get $ax=xa^2$ in $G$ which is not yet a group? If $\langle G,x\rangle$ is a group, then OK. But $\langle G,x\rangle$ is not a group.

**Q3:** Why the exponent laws hold in set $\langle G,x\rangle$? For example, Herstein uses that $xx=x^2$ and $a^2a^2=a^4$

Please explain all these questions. The same question occured in my head couple weeks ago but I did not get persuasive. I hope that this time the questions will be explained properly.

Comment: $G$ is a group, cyclic of order seven.

Comment: There is no why. The author just _define_ the multiplication on the said set in such a way.

Comment: Some concept that may be of interest: [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group).

Comment: @fkraiem, Sorry i have edited my post. I was aking why all these laws hold in new set $\{G,x\}$?

Comment: @CaveJohnson, I guess your statement is not true. The set $\{G,x\}$ should be proved that it is a group.

Comment: That does not contradict my claim. You _define_ a multiplication and then prove this multiplication satisfies the group law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are right, and that Herstein goes a bit too fast here for a beginner. (I've had many students who found this puzzling.)

But you are also going too fast by writing $\langle G, x\rangle$ too soon, that only really makes sense when we are working in some overgroup -- which as you recognise, we are not.

We have, Herstein says, a set, let's call it $\hat{G}$, of 21 elements whose names are $x^i a^j$ where $i\in \{0,1,2\}$ and $j\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. We want to define a group operation on this set.

[*Now this is not part of the definition, it's just the motivation: we want the operation of conjugation by $x$ in $\hat{G}$, $a\mapsto x^{-1}ax$ to be the automorphism $\phi:a\mapsto a^2$. What would that force the multiplication in $\hat{G}$ to be?

Well if we are to be successful, and get a group, we will have associativity and so the exponents laws, and we will need to have
$$(x^ i a^j)(x^m a^n)
=x^{i+m}x^{-m}a^{j}x^{m}a^{n}
=x^{i+m}(x^{-m}ax^{m})^{j}a^{n}
=x^{i+m}(a^{2^m})^{j}a^{n}
=x^{i+m}a^{2^{m}j+n}
$$
where of course we have to calculate the value of the exponents modulo $3$ and $7$ respectively.*]

With the motivation in our minds we **define** a binary operation $\cdot$ on $\hat{G}$ by 
$$(x^ i a^j)(x^m a^n)
:=x^{i+m}a^{2^{m}j+n} \text{ where the exponents are reduced modulo 3 and 7.}
$$

We are now faced with the tedious (but essentially trivial) task of proving that this operation is associative; that $x^0 a^0$ is a two-sided identity; and that each $x^i a^j$ has a two-sided inverse (I'll leave you to find out what it is!)

Once we've done this we have that $\hat{G}$ is indeed a group, and all is well.

If you do a few examples you'll see how this procedure will "always work" and then be happy to use Herstein's very abbreviated account for yourself.

Comment: In the first equality you wrote: $(x^ia^j)(x^ma^n)=x^{i+m}x^{-m}a^jx^ma^n=..$ Obviously, here you have used exponent laws i.e. $x^{i+m}x^{-m}=x^i$. Why it is true in this set $\hat{G}$?

Comment: Because we *want* $\hat{G}$ to be a group. Nothing is "true" in the set $\hat{G}$. We make the only definition that will make $\hat{G}$ a group with the properties we want, and then -- IMPORTANTLY -- we check that it works. The bit in italics is motivation, not mathematics.

Comment: You know, It's quite strange. We introduce exponent laws in $\hat{G}$ in order to prove that $\hat{G}$ is group. I have never met similiar before in math. Could you explain it more in detail? Still can not digest it :(

Comment: You are thinking about it upside down: the "exponent laws" are simple consequences of the Group Axioms (which we have to prove), once we have made the usual recursive definition of what $g^n$ means. We don't "introduce them in $\hat{G}$ to prove that $\hat{G}$ is a group." We define a certain binary operation (inspired of course by what we want to manufacture), define an identity, define inverses and then prove the three group axioms (associativity, identity element, inverses) hold. Only at that stage is it sensible to define $g^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and prove that the exponent rules hold.

Comment: Let me ask you a question: where are you defining $g^n$? Could you point out at this?

Comment: I don't define it anywhere. The $x^m a^n$ are just what Herstein says, "symbols". Once the definition of multiplication and inverse have been defined as I indicate you could define $g^k$ recursively for $k\ge 0$ as usual, $g^0:=e$, $g^{k+1}:=g^k g$ and then for $k<0$, $g^k:= (g^{-1})^{-k}$. You will then find (surprise, surprise) that the symbol $x^m a^0$ is just $(x^1 a^0)^{m}$ and so on.

Comment: So in order to prove that this set is group we need to define binary operation between elements, right? And then we can demonstrate all group axioms.

Comment: Sets ain't groups. We prove- as I said in the solution - that the set described there, equipped with the binary operation defined there satisfies the three group axioms: associativity, identity, inverses.

Comment: That's what I meant :)

Comment: But you have written many comments suggesting that you think it's the set which is a group. You really ought to get it clear ;-)

Comment: One more question: Why Herstein subject $x$ to the following condition: $x^{-1}a^ix=\phi(a^i)=a^{2i}$? I can not understand the motivation of that identity. Could you explain it, please? Why he conjugates $a^i$ by $x$?

Comment: Herstein wants conjugation by $x$ to mimic the automorphism $\phi$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71386/discussion-between-rfz-and-ancientmathematician).

Comment: But what do you mean by "mimic the conjugation". I can not understand the motivation of conjugation by $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 : We are told that $G$ is a cyclic group of order 7 generated by $a$. I think the unstated assumption here is that the larger object generated by $a$ and $x$ is also a group, and inherits its group operation properties from $G$.

Q2 : We are told that $G=<a>$ is a group, and we are assuming that $<a,x>$ is also a group. So $xa^2 = xx^{-1}ax = eax = ax$.

Q3 : Integer exponents are simply a short hand, so $x^2$ stands for $xx$; $x^3$ stands for $xxx$ etc. More formally, we could define $x^1=x$ and $x^{n+1} = x(x^n)$ for $n \ge 1$. The exponent law $x^ax^b = x^{a+b}$ then follows from associativity of the group operation.

Comment: I have edited my post. I am interested why all these laws are true in new set $\{G,x\}$?

Comment: He writes that "The reader can verify that one obtains, in this way, a non-abelian group of order $21$". I guess that the set $\{G,x\}$ should be proved that it is a group. We not assume that it is a group! We should prove it!

Comment: Informally,the new object inherits the group operation and identity element from the original group G. More formally, you can identify the new object with a quotient group of the free group on $\{a,x\}$. The free group consists of finite strings constructed from the symbols $a, x, a^{-1},x^{-1}$ and the group operation in the free group is concatenation of strings, which is automatically associative.

Comment: Unfortunately, i am not familiar with the notion of free groups. Is there more easy way to explain my questuons? For a very long time i can not answer them.

Comment: @RFZ: All what causes you problems come from the use of associativity in the set $\langle G, x\rangle$. I think this is implicitly assumed as an axiom for the rules which define the law of this set.